# Why use IDs for looking up data as opposed to using the title -- please help me argue my point

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help me argue my point.

I am working on a website project with a team of developers, we are developing the system in 3 parts. The one part is the API, 2 back-end and front-end. Both the front end and back-end gets and stores data by sending it to the API.

I am specifically responsible for the front end. I am using Codeigniter as my framework.

A little background: The app is a sports betting site.

This is the problem: The developers of the API use the name of for example a tournament or fixture or sport to do the lookup, I pass the name of a tournament for example:
www.example.com/sport/add_bet/{tournament_name}

The problem I have with this is that the tournament name as entered into the system by humans might have characters such as spaces, forward slashes, etc in the name.

As you can imagine using a forward slash in  the url will completely break the system, since we use them to call different controllers, actions and to pass variables.

I am trying to get them to change to using a simple primary key id field, to perform the lookup of the data. For some reason these developers don't want to do this.

The project manager that manages this project (not a programmer and no experience of programming) had a chat to them about this issue, but still they don't want to change, and they told her that it is a matter of personal preference on which way to go.

As far as I know ID's have always been the way to do it.

Could you guys/girls please help me argue my point by giving some reasons as to why I am correct or incorrect in your view. I would like to provide your answers as motivation to get them to change over to doing it the right way.

Your help/answers/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this out: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8334/why-should-i-create-an-id-column-when-i-can-use-others-as-key-fields

Comment: More info: They do have id fields as primary keys (or so they say) but they don't want to perform the lookup on them for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is the `id` will be `unique` as it is should be the `primary key`. so searching by ids will return unique results.

But the multiple record may have save `title` if you didn't `validate` them at the time of saving.

And also if you want some `joins` or something like that the `id` would help it.

And the should never trust the user and expect them to work as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is two sides:
1) You allow select single Title from dropdown and send to server only ID. Look-up by ID is way faster (assuming you are using ID as primary key). But if you have lots of Titles than you have to list all of them and user will be forced to scroll till find that Title.

2) You have simple input field to allow search only by part of Title. That way you don't have to list all Titles. As programmer, you have to escape all user input, that goes to server (via GET or POST), so that user can input even `DELETE FROM user WHERE 1` to your input field and your system will sill works fine. Also, by inputting only part of Title allow to show multiple results, while using IDs is impossible.

I prefer second approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, okay I understand that escaping and encoding the string would make it possible, but how would encode the strings for example to escape out a forward slash? I tried urlencode

Answer (score 0):

To make the look up fast, you need to place an index on the column by which you are looking up records. Primary key column always has an index. In order to use some other column you need to add an unique index, to avoid duplicates and make the search faster, which in turn makes the table larger. If you expect the table to grow (which is not too unlikely if you follow many sports and many leagues/tournaments over a number of years), it might become a problem at some point, depending on the resources in your production environment. It's not the strongest argument you can present, but it is not a bad argument either